# tt_news in Menu

Tags: typo3, typoscript

In need to create a special and complicated menu. It should display in the Level 2 all sub-page with the latest news of their parent page (level 1) (I used tt_news and I created  news for each page level 1). Here is my source code, it is composed of two parts, it shows in all level2 menu juste only the news of the first parent page(level 1).

1. The first part:

   ```
   lib.var1 < plugin.tt_news
   lib.var1 {

          code >
          code = LATEST

          templateFile= fileadmin/news_template.tmpl


          categoryMode = 0

       pid_list >
       pid_list.insertData = 1
       pid_list = {data:pid}
       catImageMode = 1
       catTextMode = 0

       latestLimit = 1

   }
   ```
2. The second part:

   ```
   lib.field_menu= HMENU
   lib.field_menu {
       entryLevel = 0

       ### first level ###
       1 = TMENU
       1 {
           noBlur = 1
           expAll = 1
           wrap = |
           NO = 1
           NO {
               allWrap = |
               ATagTitle.field = title
               }
       }

       ### secondary Level ###
       2 = TMENU
       2 {
           noBlur = 1

                       stdWrap.wrap = <ul style=""><li> | </li></ul> 
                       stdWrap.innerWrap = <div><ul>|</ul></div>
                       stdWrap.innerWrap2.preCObject =< lib.var1

           NO = 1
           NO {
               linkWrap= <li class="">|</li>
               ATagTitle.field = title

                       }
          }
      }
   }
   ```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please translate (**no google translator etc.**) your question to English as this is the official language here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
pid_list >
pid_list = TEXT
pid_list.insertData = 1
pid_list.data = field : pid
```

instead if `{data:pid}`.